# PHP: echoing array only returns the word array instead of its content

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

I am very new to PHP and hope you can help me with this.

I am fetching some data from SQL and try to create an array that I want to echo on a page.

When I echo the result from the following (`$output`) then this only returns the word "array" insteaed of the items that I am trying to add to it.

**Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and provide me a short explanation as well ?**

```
$c = "";
$i = 0;
$arr = array();
$output = ''
foreach ($objNames->names as $names) {
    $c = "<img src='images/photos/photo_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $names->member) . ".png' alt='' class='clickable flagLink trackHC' />&nbsp;" . $names->member . " &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    array_push($arr, $c);
    $i++;
}
if($i != 0) {
    $output = $arr;
}


<div id="output"><?php echo $output; ?></div>
```

Many thanks for any help, Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant just echo arrays.

You have to loop through it with a foreach for example:

```
$c = "";
$i = 0;
$arr = array();
$output = ''
foreach ($objNames->names as $names) {
    $c = "<img src='images/photos/photo_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $names->member) . ".png' alt='' class='clickable flagLink trackHC' />&nbsp;" . $names->member . " &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    array_push($arr, $c);
    $i++;
}
if($i != 0) {
    $output = $arr;
}

foreach($output as $row) {
?>
    <div id="output"><?php echo $row; ?></div>
<?php
}
```

This should work for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help ! One more question on this. Will this echo everything to the same div (which is what I need) or will it create multiple divs ?

Comment: multiple divs. put the div tags **outside** the `foreach` loop if you want printing everything in the same div

Comment: @Mike You have to see it like this: You are taking EVERY element in this array now. and for EACH element in this array, you are executing the code in the {} braces

Answer (score 2):

An array must be printed using:

```
print_r($arrayValue)
```

you can keep the print value also (**EDITED**):

```
$x = print_r($arrayValue, true)
```

but I prefer the json way if it's for logging purposes:

```
echo json_encode($arrayValue)
```

keeping in mind every value must be json-serializable.

...

Doing a plain `echo $arrayValue` will always print "Array" word without any content. Yes, it's a bit unintuitive (since other languages like python don't behave like that) but it is what it is.

Comment: answer updated due to error being detected (missing optional second argument for print_r).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to just see/print the contents of your array, try this:

```
print_r ($output);
```