# From Parse to PHP to JS, what types of data?

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966630/getting-data-out-of-this-array-in-js)This is my code in PHP

```
  $query = new ParseQuery("CourseInfo");
  $query->equalTo("Admin", "username1");
  $results = $query->find();

echo $results;
```

This is returned via the XMLHTTPRequest and a callback in my JS file.

- What does Parse send to PHP (I thought an array of objects)?
- What does PHP send to JS? (I've no idea)
- How can i access this data in JS?

Thanks!

Update: i found some of the answer here: [PHP: echoing array only returns the word array instead of its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638087/php-echoing-array-only-returns-the-word-array-instead-of-its-content)

basically, `echo $results` just returns the string "array".

Using `print_r($results) gives a very large data array/object?

I'll put this into a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966630/getting-data-out-of-this-array-in-js).

Comment: you should return json value from php to JS

Comment: What is `Parse`, a JS library? You can see the response of an AJAX request by opening the network tab in developer console, selecting the request, and clicking the `response` tab. Accessing depends on the JS request. Is `$results` a string, object, or array?

Comment: Parse is a backend / database. I didn't know about the response tab, but it's great! Unfortunately it says ARRAY.  haha, $results... i think an array of objects...