# Getting data out of this array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Finally i get some output out of PHP instead of just the word "array". This took me a day, AAAAHHHH.

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638087/php-echoing-array-only-returns-the-word-array-instead-of-its-content) for the solution)

So this is the return value from a XMLHTTP request (to PHP), via a callback in JS. I got it with `print_r` in PHP.

I post a snippet of the results here.
My new question:

- what is this data structure made of?
- how to get elements out of this structure, such as CourseID (in JS)?

  ```
  [0] => Parse\ParseObject Object
  (
      [serverData:protected] => Array
          (
              [CourseID] => DEMO2
              [EndDate] => DateTime Object
                  (
                      [date] => 2017-03-31 10:26:00.000000
                      [timezone_type] => 2
                      [timezone] => Z
                  )

              [InfoTitle1] => Welcome
              [InfoText1] => Welcome to your course, called "sense & sales". 
              [Admin] => Remco@Demo1
          )
  ```

My PHP code is

```
function getGroups(){
  $query = new ParseQuery("CourseInfo");
 $query->equalTo("Admin", "Remco@Demo1");
 $results = $query->find();


// echo $results      // this lead to the string "array"
//print_r($results);  // this leads to the complicated array
//echo "<script>\r\n var phpOutput = " . json_encode($results) . ";\r\n console.log(phpOutput);\r\n</script>";
// this leads to [{},{}]; 
}
```

Comment: Probably something like `$data[0]->CourseId`.

Comment: You'll need to serialize your array either in markup or in an AJAX call.

Comment: You've tagged this JavaScript, but I don't see any JavaScript in the question. And this question should stand on its own, without someone needing to go back and look at your other one.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a JavaScript Object, so you need to use JSON.

(JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.)

PHP has a `json_encode` function, which will do the work for you: (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

Try this:

PHP:

```
echo "<script>\r\n var phpOutput = " . json_encode($output) . ";\r\n console.log(phpOutput);\r\n</script>";
```

Press F12 in your browser to open the browser's Console log window in Developer Tools to see the new JavaScript Object.

Comment: thanks Sean! i changed $ouput and then it outputs this: <script>
 var phpOutput = [{},{}];
 console.log(phpOutput);
</script>

Comment: Check on the variable name you're `json_encode`ing.  Is it `$output`?  If not, change that variable to what it's supposed to be.  This is why it's helpful to include the code in question.

Comment: Please update your question with the PHP code so we can see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to convert your PHP object to JSON first via [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

This will allow you to easily work with it in JavaScript like you normally would with any JavaScript object.

Comment: in general it does, but with this Parse data not. That is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I stopped trying to work with this array/object in JS. But instead i managed it on the PHP side and sent the results to JS.

Now it is all simple. (-;

Comment: What do you mean you sent the results to JS?

Comment: Sure. I mean 'echo' it to JS (i don't know what this is supposed to be called (-; )

Comment: The reason I asked is because there's echo'ing it on page load, and then there's AJAX, so I wanted to clarify.  Thanks

Comment: I didn't know this. Will research it a bit !